# Looking for advice on which loop to use?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I've built a tool that produces another spreadsheet when the macro runs. In order for that sheet to be uploaded succesfully into a system, it needs to be formatted a particular way. To prevent people from not using the tool properly and messing up the formatting on the new spreadsheet, I've build a series of checks.

Each one checks if a cell has a particular string ("Please Set!") and if so, pops a msgbox and stops the macro. The idea being that it passes each check until it either hits one it fails, or passes them all and runs the code to produce the new sheet. It's a bit long-winded at the moment and I'm looking for a loop to make it neater.

```vb
If Worksheets("Input").Range("F7").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("F9").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("F13").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("F17").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("F21").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("L9").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("L13").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("L17").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
End If

If Worksheets("Input").Range("L21").Value = "Please Set!" Then
    MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
    Exit Sub
```

There's an else after this and the code to produce the sheet.

Everything is working as intended but the above code is bulky as all hell and I know there's a better way. I've looked into different loops but I'm new to VBA so I'm not sure which one would be the best to condense this down into. Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 4):

Just put your addresses to check into an array and loop through that array to check the value.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ValidateFields()
    Dim AddressesToCheck() As Variant
    AddressesToCheck = Array("F7", "F9") 'add all addresses here

    Dim Addr As Variant
    For Each Addr In AddressesToCheck
        If Worksheets("Input").Range(Addr).Value = "Please Set!" Then
            MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Addr
End Sub
```

---

*Edit according comment:*

To make your main procedure react to the result of `ValidateFields` turn it into a `Function` rather than a `Sub`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsFieldsValid() As Boolean
    Dim AddressesToCheck() As Variant
    AddressesToCheck = Array("F7", "F9") 'add all addresses here

    IsFieldsValid = True 'set all fields valid until an invalid field is found.

    Dim Addr As Variant
    For Each Addr In AddressesToCheck
        If Worksheets("Input").Range(Addr).Value = "Please Set!" Then
            MsgBox "Please complete all the fields!", vbCritical
            IsFieldsValid = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Addr
End Function
```

So you can use the result to react on your main procedure like …

```
Public Sub MainProcedure()
    If IsFieldsValid Then  '<< this will validate the fields and return `True` if they are all valid or `False` if one (or more) are not valid.
        'do stuff if validation passed
    Else
        'do other stuff if one (or more) fields are not valid
        Exit Sub 'for example abort main procedure
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! One thing though, I've set that as it's own sub in another module so I can call it in my main module sub. This works fine but I need the main sub to stop running if this sub hits any instances of Please Set!, which my previous long-winded code did fine. How would I implement that in this solution?

Comment: Therefore you would need to turn `ValidateFields` into a `Function` rather than a `Sub` that reports the status to your main procedure so you can react to the result of `ValidateFields`. See my edit.